# Move one div to another div via jQuery

Tags: jquery

There is an application generating container dynamically and I am trying to move that into another container. Its pretty simple but the function behaving weird.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="column-4">
    <div class="social">
        social-1
    </div>
    <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
<div class="column-4">
    <div class="social">
        social-2
    </div>
    <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
<div class="column-4">
    <div class="social">
        social-3
    </div>
    <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.column-4').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.social').appendTo('.fbto');
    return false;
});
```

As per the above simple code I am trying to move `.social` div into `.fbto`. But no luck.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: By "behaving weird" do you mean there is a specific error, it's doing something you don't want, or it's not doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

1. Remove the `return false`. Because it will stop the loop execution.
2. Get the corresponding `.fbto` element and append to it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.column-4').each(function() {
    var fbto = $(this).find('.fbto');
    $(this).find('.social').appendTo(fbto);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-4">
  <div class="social">
    social-1
  </div>
  <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
<div class="column-4">
  <div class="social">
    social-2
  </div>
  <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
<div class="column-4">
  <div class="social">
    social-3
  </div>
  <div class="fbto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks..it works that way.. but can you please help me understand. If I don't define variable and keep the syntax - appendTo($(this).find('.fbto')); then why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @MufeedAhmad This way also should work. What problem you are facing?

Comment: thanks.. it was my bad. thank you so much for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke the each function after document loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.column-4').each(function(){
         $(this).find('.social').appendTo('.fbto');
     });
});
```